Doesn't respond to setOnDrag Javafx events
I have a Pane into which I want to move files, but for some reason it doesn’t trigger on these events, I’m already confused, the pane processes all events except setOnDragOver, setOnDragEntered, setOnDragExited, setOnDragDropped
val drag = Pane().apply {
            id = "dragFile"
            layoutX = 28.0
            layoutY = 58.0

            val dragImage = ImageView().apply {
                id = "drag"
                fitWidth = 80.0
                fitHeight = 80.0
                layoutX = 60.0
                layoutY = 20.0
            }
            val dragText = Label("text").apply {
                id = "dragText"
                layoutX = 29.0
                layoutY = 100.0
            }

            children.addAll(dragImage, dragText)

            setOnDragOver { event ->
                if (event.dragboard.hasFiles()) {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY)
                }
                event.consume()
            }
            setOnDragEntered { event ->
                if (event.dragboard.hasFiles()) {
                    id = "dragFileActive"
                }
                event.consume()
            }
            setOnDragExited { _ -> id = "dragFile" }
            setOnDragDropped { event ->
                if (event.dragboard.hasFiles()) {
                    event.isDropCompleted = true
                    handler(event.dragboard.files)
                }
                event.consume()
            }
        }

I tried outputting a message to the console, even that didn’t work.
setOnDragOver { println("drag over") }
setOnDragEntered { println("drag entered") }
setOnDragExited { println("drag exited") }
setOnDragDropped { println("drag drop") }


Minimal Example
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane
import javafx.stage.Stage
import java.io.File

class FileDropApp : Application() {
 
    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
        val pane = Pane().apply {
            id = "importFile"
            layoutX = 273.0
            layoutY = 135.0
            prefWidth = 400.0
            prefHeight = 300.0
            style = "-fx-background-color: lightgray;"
 
            val dropArea = Pane().apply {
                id = "dragFile"
                layoutX = 50.0
                layoutY = 50.0
                prefWidth = 300.0
                prefHeight = 200.0
                style = "-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black;"
 
                setOnDragOver { event ->
                    if (event.dragboard.hasFiles()) {
                        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY)
                    }
                    event.consume()
                }
 
                setOnDragEntered { event ->
                    if (event.dragboard.hasFiles()) {
                        style = "-fx-background-color: lightgreen; -fx-border-color: black;"
                    }
                }
 
                setOnDragExited { _ -> style = "-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black;" }
                setOnDragDropped { event ->
                    if (event.dragboard.hasFiles()) {
                        val files = event.dragboard.files
                        event.isDropCompleted = true
                        handleFiles(files)
                    } else {
                        event.isDropCompleted = false
                    }
                    event.consume()
                }
            }
            children.addAll(dropArea)
        }
 
        val scene = Scene(pane, 800.0, 600.0)
        primaryStage.title = "File Drop Example"
        primaryStage.scene = scene
        primaryStage.show()
    }
 
    private fun handleFiles(files: List<File>) {
        files.forEach { file ->
            println("File dropped: ${file.absolutePath}")
        }
    }
}
 
fun main() {
    Application.launch(FileDropApp::class.java)
}


Are you trying to drag files from one part of your application to another or are you trying to drag files from an external application to your application? Which version of Java and JavaFX are you using? Which OS are you on? Can you provide a more complete [mre]?

I'm trying to drag selected files from desktop or folder into an application, using Java 22, javafx version 22.0.2, OC: Windows
code

Your code (from pastebin) works for me using Java/JavaFX 22.0.2 on Windows 10.

@James_D I believe setOnDragDetected and startDragAndDrop are only needed when initiating drag-and-drop from within the JavaFX application. Since the OP is trying to drag-and-drop files from the desktop, their code should be working (and it does for me).

@KirillNemtyrev Note questions should be as self-contained as possible. That means, for instance, that your [mre] must be in the question itself as code-formatted text. I copied the code from your pastebin link and added it to your question for you this time. Though I added the imports needed to make it runnable. Please make any [edit]s if and as needed.

@Slaw Thanks; I didn't notice that in the comment.

@Slaw Thanks for fixing it, I’ll know, but I still have the problem, when I run the code from the example, there may be something wrong with Windows 11. I found a guide on YouTube but it still didn’t help.
video

Works fine for me too with JDK22/JavaFX22/Mac OS X 14.4.

I just tried your code on my Windows 11 machine with the same Java/JavaFX versions and it worked for me still. Are you running your JavaFX application "as administrator" (possibly indirectly; e.g., because your IDE is elevated)? On Windows, drag-and-drop from a non-elevated app to an elevated one is not allowed. And the process responsible for the desktop (explorer.exe I think?) is likely not elevated.

@Slaw, Wow, indeed, I ran the IDE as administrator, checked without and everything worked, thank you very much!

Preface: You've confirmed in a comment that running your application "as an administrator" was the source of your problem, so I'm moving my guess to an answer.

So, your problem is with dragging files from your desktop to your application but your application isn't receiving any events. Given your code works for others on multiple operating systems, including the one you're using, your problem is likely something to do with your environment specifically rather than the code itself. Now, there isn't really enough information in your question to give a definitive answer, but since the problem is specifically with drag-and-drop on Windows there is a likely reason:
You're running your application with administrative privileges.
On Windows, drag-and-drop from a non-elevated application to an elevated one is not allowed. And the desktop's process is not elevated. There may be similar rules on other operating systems, I'm not sure.
Though I assume you're not intentionally running your application with administrative privileges. But if you launch your application from an elevated process then your application will inherit the elevated state, at least by default. Check to see if your IDE, or whatever you're using to launch your application, is elevated. If it is, then try relaunching your IDE (or whatever) without administrative privileges. Or, if you need your IDE (or whatever) to be elevated for some reason, try launching your application another way (e.g., from a terminal that isn't running as administrator).
